# How can I get the unique items in a bash list?

Tags: linux, bash

If I have a list in bash

```
L="11 22 11 33 22 44"
```

Is there a clean way to get to "11 22 33 44" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way:

```
$ L="11 22 11 33 22 44"
$ L=$(echo $L | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -nu)    
$ echo $L
11 22 33 44
```

Using tr, the numbers are split to individual lines, and sort is used to sort the numbers(-n) and remove the duplicate ones(-u).

Comment: You can leave off the `| xargs`.  Because of the way the shell handles multi-line output from a `$(…)` command, `L=$(echo $L | tr ' ' '\n' | sort –u)` is enough.

Comment: @Scott : thanks scott for pointing it out, updated the solution....

Comment: Clean and easy.  'tr' was the the part I was missing.

Answer (score 5):

A common pattern in some other programming languages is to store each value as a 'key' in a hash or dictionary or associative array, and rely on the implementation to keep hash keys unique.

```
declare -A items=()
for item in $L; do
    items[$item]=1
done
L=${!items[*]}
```

(Unfortunately, the `bash` implementation is about 2× slower than `sort -u`.)

Comment: +1..its always a pleasure looking at pure shell solutions..

Comment: @grawity If you are referring to the accepted solution, I cannot confirm that the bash implementation is 2x slower. On the contrary, it is more than 100x faster.

Comment: ..continuing.. For the given string that is. Your bash implementation keeps being faster if the string contains up to ~2000 elements (on my system).

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Gurus answer above, if you have an array you can:

```
$ L=(11 22 11 33 22 44)
$ echo ${L[@]}
11 22 11 33 22 44
$ L=($(echo ${L[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -nu))
$ echo ${L[@]}
11 22 33 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one I've found useful for checking the list of unique IPs connecting to your servers, from the 'netstat' command is this:

Netstat Output Example

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.196:8009            192.168.21.124:45921          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.7.196:8009            192.168.21.124:51579          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.7.196:8009            192.168.20.12:20213           TIME_WAIT

Command Example

In this example I'm starting by filtering the TCP port, cutting out the local information, sorting the list and then piping it to the 'uniq' command.

netstat -an | grep ":8009" | cut -d " " -f 28 | cut -d ":" -f 1 | sort -u

What I get is a list of the 2 unique foreign IP addresses connecting to my system.

192.168.21.124
192.168.21.12

If you did some fancy monitoring stuff, you can graph the total number of unique nodes connecting, compare the list to your white list of allowed IPs, add non-authorized IPs to your black list, etc.

Comment: While this is a useful application for this problem, it does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I guess this version beats all the rest! Mainly because of no need for `eval` in bash

```
$ L="11 22 11 33 22 44"
$ readarray -t L < <(printf "%s\n" ${L[@]} | sort -u)
$ printf "%s\n" ${L[@]}
11
22
33
44
```